# https in webmaster tools from http

Tags: ssl, https

We have a couple of webshops that we have moved from http to https and also made a new webmaster tools. Now we are waiting to see the index go down on the http and up on the https. The https shows the first indexes, but by the old one with http we do not yet see any change.

We have moved the shops now one and a half weeks ago. When you look in Google you see that he takes the homepage and other pages with https.

Do we have to be patient and can this take up long or should we already see the index going down?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS, then it's just a matter of time. Here's a few things that may help:

- Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS using a 301 redirect
- Make sure the Sitemaps are pointing to the HTTPS links and not HTTP
- Set the [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). The common setting is generally 1 year